# smooth animation using deviceorientation

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm creating a game using the device deviceorientation with the createjs library,

I have a graphic that moves on it's x axis depending on the tilt of the phone.

The problem I'm having is the graphic animation is jerky.

I'm wondering if it's down to the logic I'm using?

I have two functions "handleOrientation" and "render"

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);

function handleOrientation(event) {
nextX = car.x;   
x = Math.round(event.beta);  // In degree in the range [-180,180]
y = Math.round(event.gamma); // In degree in the range [-90,90]
// Because we don't want to have the device upside down
  // We constrain the x value to the range [-90,90]
    if (x >  90) { x =  90};
    if (x < -90) { x = -90};
    hit = "nothing"
  // To make computation easier we shift the range of 
  // x and y to [0,180]
    x += 90;
    //y += 90;
    if(y >0){
        nextX = car.x +carSpeed; 
    }
    if(y < 0){
        nextX =  car.x -carSpeed; 
      };
    car.nextX= nextX;
}

function render(){
if(gameState=="game started"){
  if (car.nextX < 0 + car.width / 2){
    car.x = 0 + car.width / 2 ; 
    }else if(car.nextX > stage.canvas.width - car.width / 2){
        car.x = stage.canvas.width - car.width / 2; 
    } else{
          car.x = car.nextX;
    }
  }
}

 function tick(){
     render();
     stage.update();
    }
```

I know that deviceorientation is quite sensitive, maybe calling the function in a timer, so it's not updating so often?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

> maybe calling the function in a timer, so it's not updating so often

Instead of updating the location on every tick, you could read multiple readings before updating the position, take an average, and update position using that average.
Alternatively, you could update the position on every tick but use last N readings to get the average in a similar way.

Here's a simple example of the second suggestion:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);

xAvg = 0;
yAvg = 0;

//how much stored "average" affects current speed
coef = 0.9;

function handleOrientation(event) {
nextX = car.x;   
x = Math.round(event.beta);  // In degree in the range [-180,180]
y = Math.round(event.gamma); // In degree in the range [-90,90]
// Because we don't want to have the device upside down
  // We constrain the x value to the range [-90,90]
    if (x >  90) { x =  90};
    if (x < -90) { x = -90};
    hit = "nothing"
  // To make computation easier we shift the range of 
  // x and y to [0,180]
    x += 90;
    y += 90;

    //include current readings to the "average"
    xAvg = xAvg*coef + x*(1.0 - coef);
    yAvg = yAvg*coef + y*(1.0 - coef);

    x = xAvg;
    y = yAvg;

    if(y >0){
        nextX = car.x +carSpeed; 
    }
    if(y < 0){
        nextX =  car.x -carSpeed; 
      };
    car.nextX= nextX;
}

function render(){
if(gameState=="game started"){
  if (car.nextX < 0 + car.width / 2){
    car.x = 0 + car.width / 2 ; 
    }else if(car.nextX > stage.canvas.width - car.width / 2){
        car.x = stage.canvas.width - car.width / 2; 
    } else{
          car.x = car.nextX;
    }
  }
}

 function tick(){
     render();
     stage.update();
    }
```

I have not tested this, and you should play around with coef value.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer, do you have any examples of how I'd go about this?